# How to create Xarray DataSet with a Pandas MultiIndex for one of the dimensions?

Tags: python, pandas, multidimensional-array, python-xarray

I'm trying to create an `Xarray` `DataArray` object with one of the dimensions having tuples from a `Pandas MultIndex` object.

Here's the code I'm trying:

```
A = np.random.normal(size=(100,10,5))

index_samplespecific = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(map(lambda x: ("test", f"Sample_{x}"), range(A.shape[0]))).map(tuple)
xr.DataArray(
        data=A, 
        name="test",
        dims=["Samples", "Iterations", "Edges"], 
        coords={
            "Samples":list(index_samplespecific), 
            "Iterations":list(range(A.shape[1])),
            "Edges":list(range(A.shape[2])), 
        },
)
```

Here's the error:

```
MissingDimensionsError: cannot set variable 'Samples' with 2-dimensional data without explicit dimension names. Pass a tuple of (dims, data) instead.
```